# Better way to implement this spring pre authentication filter?

Tags: java

This class is bugging me, I probably need some input as to the best way to refactor it. This is a spring security filter, so the two methods - getPreAuthenticatedPrincipal(HttpServletRequest request) and getPreAuthenticatedCredentials(HttpServletRequest request) will get called whenever somebody logs in.

Ideally you should be able to do request.getParameter(“username”) and request.getParameter(“password”) - but those return null in my application, and you can only do request.getInputStream() once - after that, the method returns a null.

So I have to create a JSONObject member variable and store the request parameters in the JSONObject for use in both methods.  Is there a better way to design this class?

Thanks for any input

```
     public class UserAuthenticationFilter extends AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter {


 protected JSONObject jsonObj = null;

        @Override
        protected Object getPreAuthenticatedPrincipal(HttpServletRequest request) {
        try {

                String jsonString = IOUtils.toString(request.getInputStream());
                System.out.println(jsonString);
                if (jsonObj == null) {
                    jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonString);
                }

            } catch (IOException e) { // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            String userName = jsonObj.getString("username");
            System.out.println(userName);
            return userName;

        }

        @Override   
        protected Object getPreAuthenticatedCredentials(HttpServletRequest request) {

            String passWd = jsonObj.getString("password");
            System.out.println(passWd);         return passWd;

        }
    }
```

Comment: I am confused. Why are you writing a "PreAuthenticatedAuthentication" filter if you still need to authenticate the user?

Comment: Why are the credentials part of the request body? Auth filters are usually used with credentials in the http headers

Comment: I can't change the type of filter or how credentials get to the filter.  This question is more of a java question than a 'spring security' question anyway.

Comment: @rmlan - I work in a team, there are other systems involved and I don't control them.  I'm just working to spec given to me by other people - and it's a bit presumptuous of you to pass judgement on a set of  systems you know nothing about.  To answer your question in the general sense - we have to use the preauthentication filter because we have a number systems in our 'filter chain' that we need to authenticate against in our login process.  This piece is just one part of the authentication process and needs to happen at this point in the login process.